# In VS2022, Facing issue while setting Optimize tag as true in C# project

Tags: c#, optimization, compiler-errors, visual-studio-2022, autotest

We are seeing this “Common language runtime Exception in an Invalid Program” error when we use release mode dll in unit tests . AutoTest are Passing when we use Debug mode dll

We observed that Optimize setting (true) was true in release mode dll, As per Microsoft suggestion we tried building dll (without changing the Framework Version) in older versions i.e, the with VS2013, ATs are Getting Passed. May be VS2022 is doing Heavy optimization for this dll.

So we need to know What was differences done by Microsoft for Optimize setting in VS2013 (Older version) and newer Version of VS2022 ? Can you help us to resolve this issue. Can we have any workaround for it quickly ? Because we are seeing this issue only in VS22 compiler.

Need a solution or workaround for this

Comment: Did you create another account? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77386264/enabling-optimizetrue-optimize-in-visual-studio-2022-makes-the-autotest-fail

Comment: We still cannot help you if you do not provide any debugging details. "AutoTest Fails" gives us no information to go on. The solution is almost certainly to fix whatever code that is relying on not being optimized.

Comment: It may be due to the fact that your project has an old version of the csproj file format. VS2013 uses the older .csproj project file format. VS2022 uses the new .csproj format. In addition, if your project is not in the old version of csproj file format, you can check whether the debug setting is x64 or x86 when debugging your code.